# Load a modal popup if a session exists?

Tags: php, session, bootstrap-modal

Hi as the title suggests I would like to load a modal popup if a session exists on page load.

I currently use this as a sort of Flash message. Example if a form is submitted the php script creates  success session with a success message in it.

Then redirects to the previous page. on that page is a an If statement for checking if the success session exists then echos it out if it does and then destroys the session so it does show again if the page is reloaded.

So instead of showing the success message I would like a modal window to open.

I would have thought this would have been quite simple but I just cant seem to to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am sure this is a duplicate and probably could have easily been found with google... YES this is possibly.

You could do something like:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) { ?>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Success</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="close btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

This is purely as an example. I would do a lot of things differently but this should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the kind of answer I was after! I have searched Google for the past few hours and not found a thing, which is why I am here now. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. If it helped you out please accept the answer so people can find it in the future!

Comment: I will be sure to post my resulting code here too if it all works out.

Answer (score 0):

Again Thanks for your help. Here is the solution I have used with the help form Dish_Rex (Thank you).

I have another PHP script working in the background, on from submission in creates a session called 'loyalty' and redirects back to the working page.

This page then checks if the 'loyalty' session is set and the calls the modal to load. Then unset's the session so it doesn't show again on page reload.

```
<?php 
    if(Session::exists('loyalty')) {
        echo "<script> $(function(){ $(window).load(function(){ $('.modal_card').rsModal(); }); }); </script>";
        unset($_SESSION['loyalty']);
    }
?>
```

I hope this is of help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

tried a couple of things, this worked best for me:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    $error = "
<script>$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
            .html('<div><h6> ".$_SESSION['error']."</h6></div>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                dialogClass: \"alert\",
                autoOpen: true,
                // width: 'auto',
                resizable: false,
                background: '#0480be',
                close: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
            </script>";
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```